# How to change dialog title when it is opened

Tags: angular

To open dialog:

```
  let dialogRef = dialog.open(UserProfileComponent, {
                    height: '400px',
                    width: '600px',
                 });
```

dialog:

```
         <h2 mat-dialog-title>Delete all</h2>
         <mat-dialog-content>Are you sure?</mat-dialog-content>
         <mat-dialog-actions>
           <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>No</button>               
           <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Yes</button>
         </mat-dialog-actions>
```

Now, I want to change the title before it is rendered, so that it should get displayed with my title instead of "Delete all"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass data through the open method like that :

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(UserProfileComponent, {
   height: '400px',
   width: '600px',
   data: { modalTitle: 'Your title' },
});
```

In your modal component, you can get the object data by doing so

```
...
constructor(
   public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<UserProfileComponent>,
   @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
 console.log(this.data) // Here the data you passed through the method open
}
...
```

In your template

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>{{ data.modalTitle }}</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>Are you sure?</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>No</button>               
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Yes</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

More info here [Modal material doc](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a binded variable from your controller like this :

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>{{dialogTitle}}</h2>
```

And whenever you want, you can change this from your controller.